# If $a_n\to0,$ then $\sum a_n$ and $\sum (a_n + a_{n+1})$ converge/diverge together?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$, a sequence suh that $\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{a}_{n}}=0$
and the series: $\sum a_n$, $\sum (a_n + a_{n+1})$

Prove/Disprove: The series converge/diverge together.

I'll be glad for an hint or a guidance.

Comment: Thank you all for the variety of answers! it's great to see how each one of you approach the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if $\sum_1^\infty(a_n +a_{n+1})$ converges and $a_n\to0,$ then $\sum_1^{\infty }a_n$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586752/prove-that-if-sum-1-inftya-n-a-n1-converges-and-a-n-to0-then-sum)

Comment: I never retracted from my closing vote for the duplicate mentionned above. I wonder who had the right to theft my user identity to retract it for me. I guess it is a bot, after the closing of that duplicate with a link towards here, but I find this unfair. After all, why prevent me and other people to vote for changing the direction of the link between these two posts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^N(a_n+a_{n+1})=a_{N+1}-a_1+2\sum_{n=1}^N a_n $$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^Na_n = \frac{a_0-a_{N+1}+\sum_{n=1}^N(a_1+a_{n+1})}2 $$

Comment: What you did is showing that each series can be written as the other multiplied by a constant. Right? That's cool!

Comment: As $a_{N+1}\to 0$, if we know tha the partial sums on the right converge as $N\to\infty$, then so does the partial sum on the left

Comment: This answer is my prefered one on this page, but see also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4586758/386889

Answer (score 4):

If 
$$\sum_0 ^{\infty} a_n $$does converge  to some value $L$ then
$$ \sum_0 ^{N} (a_n + a_{n+1}) = 2\sum_0 ^{N} a_n  + a_{N+1} -a_0  \to 2L - a_0$$
As $a_n \to 0$

So conversely we know we can write
$$
\sum_0 ^{N} (a_n + a_{n+1}) - a_{N+1} +a_0 = 2\sum_0 ^{N} a_n  
$$

And if $\sum_0 ^{N} (a_n + a_{n+1})$ converges to some $L'$ then we have 
$$\sum_0 ^{\infty} (a_n + a_{n+1}) - a_{N+1} +a_0 = 2\sum_0 ^{\infty} a_n = L' + a_0 
$$
So then 
$$
\sum_0 ^{\infty} a_n = \frac {L' + a_0} {2}
$$
So one of the series converges iff the other does.

Comment: But $\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{(-1)}^{n}}\ne 0$. Your counter-example isn't good.

Comment: @AnnieOK sorry, missed that hypothesis, I'll edit my post

Answer (score 3):

The second sum can be written as $$\begin{align*}\sum (a_n+a_{n+1})&=(a_1+a_2)+(a_2+a_3)+...=a_1+2a_2+2a_3+...\\\\&=-a_1+2\sum a_n \sim \sum a_n \end{align*}$$ where the symbol $\sim$ means that they behave the same as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Consider $a_n = (-1)^n + 1/n^2$

Comment: How does this make $a_n\to 0$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Ah. Didn't notice that requirement. I was showing that $\sum a_n$ could diverge while $\sum(a_n + a_{n+1})$ converges. My bad, thanks for pointing this out.