# Prove that if $\sum_1^\infty(a_n +a_{n+1})$ converges and $a_n\to0,$ then $\sum_1^{\infty }a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I prove that if
$
\sum_{1}^{\infty }(a_n +a_{n+1})$ converges and that  $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n\to 0) $  then $\sum_{1}^{\infty }(a_n)
$ also converges?

I tried to prove it by contradiction and assume that $\sum_{1}^{\infty }(a_n)$ diverges

so if $\sum_{1}^{\infty }(a_n)$ diverges then also $2*\sum_{1}^{\infty }(a_n)$ diverges

which equals to $\sum_{1}^{\infty }(a_{n+1}+a_{n+1})+2*a_1$

but I got stuck there and I have no Idea on how to continue.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Write down the partial sums of $
\sum_{1}^{\infty }(a_n +a_{n+1})$

Comment: "$\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n\to 0) $" is formally not correct. Write $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0.$

Comment: Hint: $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {a_n }  = \frac{1}{2}a_1  - \frac{1}{2}a_{N + 1}  + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {(a_n  + a_{n + 1} )} .
$$ We know by assumption that on the RHS everyone converges as $N\to +\infty$.

Comment: Yes, that details geetha290krm's hint.

Comment: Duplicate: [If $a_n\to0,$ then $\sum a_n$ and $\sum (a_n + a_{n+1})$ converge/diverge together?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769971/series-prove-disprove-a-statement).

Comment: I retracted my close vote for duplicate. Ater discussion below my answer, I find it more appropriate to link these two posts in the other direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the sequence $(a_n)$ converges then $\sum_1^\infty(a_n-a_{n+1})$ is a [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) convergent series.

If moreover $\sum_1^\infty(a_n+a_{n+1})$ converges then (by adding the two series and dividing by $2$) $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges.

Comment: Note that the hypothesis that the limit of $(a_n)$ is $0$ was redundant : if $a_n\to\ell$ and $\sum_1^\infty(a_n+a_{n+1})$ converges, then $0=\lim(a_n+a_{n+1})=2\ell.$

Comment: What if $a_n=(-1)^n$?

Comment: Then the limit of $(a_n)$ does not exist. In my answer, I used the existence of the limit but not its value.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. We have to assume that $a_n$ converges but it is unnecessary to say that the limit is $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! that really helped me.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I searched for a duplicate, didn't succeed in finding one, then answered, and later found one and voted to close (and improved both titles!). Note also that my answer looks smarter than those of the duplicate I proposed.

Comment: "I searched for a duplicate, didn't succeed in finding one, then answered, and later found one and voted to close (and improved both titles!)." So did I. We should search *even harder* for duplicates next time.  "Note also that my answer looks smarter than those of the duplicate I proposed." That's subjective: I don't find your answer spectacular - but you might. But if you think your answer is different, then you can add it as an answer of the duplicated (original) question.

Comment: "So did I" ? *I* did search "even harder" (and then made both titles easier to find), so you didn't have to ;-).  My answer here is not "spectacular" but more original than all those of the duplicate, which are similar to eachother and to 
geetha290krm's hint above. This is why it got 5 upvotes for the moment, and it may interest more readers, so I leave it here. A solution would be to inverse the link to duplicate, i.e. vote for closing the old post and link it to this one.

Answer (score -1):

We can use Cauchy test: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ converges iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists M \forall n > m > M: \left|\sum\limits_{i=m}^n a_i\right| < \epsilon$.

For any $\varepsilon > 0$, let $M_0$ be such that for any $n > m > M_0$ we have $\left|\sum\limits_{i=m}^n a_i + a_{i + 1}\right| < \epsilon / 4$.

Let $M_1$ be such that for any $i > M_1$ we have $|a_i| < \epsilon / 4$ (here we need $a_i \to 0$).

Then for $M = \max(M_0, M_1)$ for any $n > m > M$ we have \begin{align*}\left|\sum\limits_{i=m}^n a_i + a_{i + 1}\right| & = \left|a_m + 2\cdot \sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{n} a_i + a_{n + 1}\right| \\ & \leq |a_m| + 2\cdot\left|\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{n} a_i\right| + |a_{n + 1}| \\ & \leq \epsilon / 4 + 2 \cdot \epsilon / 4 + \epsilon / 4 = \epsilon.\end{align*}

Comment: Shouldn't you estimate $\sum_m^n a_i$ at the end? Why do you consider $\sum_m^n (a_i+a_{i+1})$ again?

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.